# Batch cmd to see if dir exists on remote linux server

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way to check whether a directory exits on a remote linux server from a windows machine. I'm a bit new to batch scripting, done mostly bash.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
if exist "\\server\share\folder\" (echo yes) else (echo no)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. write a shell script to check if folder exists on linux machine or not.
2. use plink on windows machine to execute that script remotely on linux

example:

plink.exe -v -pw %Linux_PW% -P %SSHPORT_NO% %Linux_User%@%Linux_Machine% **rm -rf %Target_Dir%/***